# Adding admob ads to phonegap app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, admob, phonegap-build

I am now using **Phonegap build**

I am a beginner with JavaScript

Now I  gone along with this

https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/wiki/00.-How-To-Use-with-PhoneGap-Build

My `config.xml` contains

```html
<gap:plugin name="com.google.cordova.admob" source="plugins.cordova.io" />
```

and my `index.html` contain these JS and HTML

```js
var admobid = {};
if( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) { 
    admobid = { // for Android
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-5064752282990502/4341809673',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-5064752282990502/5818542873'
    };
} else if(/(ipod|iphone|ipad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    admobid = { // for iOS
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/4806197152',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/7563979554'
    };
} else {
    admobid = { // for Windows Phone
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/8878394753',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/1355127956'
    };
}

function initApp() {
    if (AdMob) {
        AdMob.createBanner({
            adId : admobid.banner,
            position : AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
            autoShow : true
        });
    }
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', initApp, false);
```

```html
<body onload="initApp()">
  
  bla bla bla bla
<body>
```

**Where the Error and How I can display the ads at the bottom of the page ??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created this project for every one who need to use **admob** inside his app
https://github.com/Microsmsm/Admob-starter

Comment: the very first error, if we run in browser to test, is : "Uncaught ReferenceError: AdMob is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

First, run some console logs on the variables to see if they exist. You can use Chrome inspect to see the console if you plug your phone in.

Second, make sure it's at least 24 hours since you set the Admob instance up at Google. I always find nothing works for at least 24 hours and then bang - it's working.